# laravel sanctum - vuejs, 401 (Unauthorized) in live server while trying to get user info

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have developed this in laravel vuejs, used laravel sanctum for authentication. The app works fine in localhost, But getting this error while I did this in the live domain. I am sharing the error where I was trying to get user info :

[image]

The screenshot of header :

[image]

I am sharing the .env:

```
SESSION_DRIVER=cookie
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
SESSION_DOMAIN=localhost
SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE=false
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAIN=localhost,localhost:8080
```

From sanctum.php

```
'stateful' => explode(',', env('SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS', 
    'localhost,localhost:8080')),
```

From kernel :

```
'api' => [
        \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
        'throttle:api',
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],
```

from bootstrap.js

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

And from component :

```
created() {
    axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${this.token}`
    axios.get('/api/user').then(response => {
       localStorage.setItem('userInfo', JSON.stringify(response.data))
       let getUser = localStorage.getItem('userInfo')
       this.currentUser = JSON.parse(getUser)
    }).catch(errors => {
        console.log(errors)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your POST request to /api/user-login is returning a server error(500). Maybe that's why its not returning the auth token or cookie

You need to fix the server error first

Comment: The server error is fixed, still getting the error, is there any chance I misconfigured stateful domain ?